# Why my Unity FPS drops in Build but not in Editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

I am measuring the FPS rate counting the Update() calls in my Unity game. In the Editor, FPS are large, peaking at ~200FPS. However, when I build the game into an .exe, FPS are fixed at ~60FPS. What can be causing this issue?

I've tried to disable VSYNC, but the problem persists.

Comment: And? What does the [Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html) say?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use unity profiler, this will give you better vision of what causes the drop frame.